# Get the result of a fetch in the same JS "strand"?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch, es6-promise

By the word "strand" I'm referring to the "thread" in which a sequence of JS commands is executed. But as far as I understand it these aren't really "threads", since there is only one thread in (browser) JS.

With this:

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    redirect: 'follow', 
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', 
    body: JSON.stringify(data) 
  });
  return response;
}
```

... and then this:

```
(async function(){

    // let deliveredData

    // launch a time-consuming call:
    const resultOfPostData = postData( 'ajaxProcessor_jq.cgi', { table: 'contacts' })
    .then( response => {
        console.log( 'response' )
        console.log( response ) // class Response
        console.log( `response.status ${response.status}`      )
        if( response.status == 200 ){
            data = response.json();
            console.log( 'data' );
            console.log(data); // this is a Promise... state "pending"
            return data
        }
        throw `bad return status: ${response.status}`
    })
    .then( data => {
        // now the "payload" has been delivered in this "strand"
        // deliveredData = data
        console.log( data ); // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
    })
    .catch(( err ) => {
        console.log( 'err' );
        console.log( err );
    });

    console.log( 'resultOfPostData' )
    console.log( resultOfPostData ) // Promise with state "pending"

    await resultOfPostData

    console.log( 'resultOfPostData after await:' )
    console.log( resultOfPostData ) // Promise with state "fulfilled"

    // can I get the result of the Promise here?
    // console.log( 'deliveredData:' )
    // console.log( deliveredData )

})()
```

The second `then`, where the payload JSON data is delivered, is obviously somewhere where you can do something with that data.

One way of getting the payload data in the calling strand is by the method you can see if you uncomment all the lines containing `deliveredData`. But this looks clunky.

Is there a better way of obtaining that same data in the original "strand" after `await` has completed?

Comment: FYI Javascript is single-threaded. You're talking about synchronicity here, not threading

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: All you need is already in your script. You're just missing a `return`

Comment: I'd also suggest you either use `async`/`await` or `promise.then()` mixing them up is just confusing

Comment: If you replace "strand" with *promise chain* or *chain of tasks*, this is actually quite accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It rarely makes sense to mix manual `.then` chaining and `await` (as they do basically the same thing under the hood). Your code can be written as:

```
try { 
  const res = await postData( 'ajaxProcessor_jq.cgi', { table: 'contacts' });
  if(!res.ok) {
    // handle status code
  }
  const result = await res.json();
  // do stuff with result
} catch {
  // handle error occured while fetching / parsing
}
```